# Apply font-size to only certain child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a project (a label maker) where I need to define a font-size and then apply in percentage the desired size to text elements.

This is working as expected but when I set font-size to the parent div (containing text, images, barcodes...), all the images get an offset of the font-size in pixels I set.

Since I will generate a PDF, the font-size of my text is stored in my db as an int and will be used as pt (point type). To achieve this, I set my font-size of the parent div to its height and set the font-size of my child elements as a percentage.

Basically I am doing this :

```
<div id='template' style="font-size: (labelHeight) + px">
    <div id='text' style="font-size: {{100*(field.fontSize*0.352778)/field.template.format.height }}%">
        <p>My text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img id='myImage'>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a simplification of my code (the syntax is not correct here but it is just to show you how it works).

I store my **field.template.format.height** in *mm* and my **fontSize** as an *int*.
The *0.352778* value comes from the fact that **1pt** = **0.352778mm**.

Basically I want my fontSize of my *template* div to apply only to *text* elements.

Comment: Use style only for the <p> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `font-size` property specifies the size of the text. If other elements inside the template `div` are affected by it, is it possible that their size/padding/margin is specified using `em` units, which are proportional to the font size. I'd suggest using `rem` units instead because they are proportional to the global font size and therefore unaffected by the changes of the template `div`'s font size.

Comment: Thank you, this totally works, I applied font-size: 1rem to all my elements that are not text and everything is displayed as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if the parent div has a font size and it child will inherit it.
to fix this problem you should specify it one by one

For example `<p style="style ETC"></p>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).